# What is a Cordova based project

Tags: cordova, directory

I just started a new PhoneGap(Cordova) project and I get an error telling me that the current working directory is not a Cordova-based project:

```
Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project
```

Could someone please explain to me what this means (other than the fact that the current working directory doesn't work with Cordova) and how I could change it? I'm sorry for my lack of knowledge towards fixing these issues, I hope someone could help me fix this error.

With kind regards
     -Theodore Tremblot

Comment: Wht is inside that directory? Have you created the cordova solution?

Comment: @Spharah no I haven't done anything. The directory is empty (to my knowledge). What can I do to check this?

Comment: One of the framework that uses cordova is [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) . you can create a basic cordova project in few seconds.

Comment: @Spharah Ok, thanks. So would ionic be like an IDE on which I could create a Cordova project? If so that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova/Phonegap is a nice container to work inside for HTML, CSS, and javascript applications that allows access to native device APIs (such as the camera). Getting this error means you haven't created a Cordova project but you're trying to do something Cordova-like (not sure what you're input is). If you want to create a cordova project, it's simple:

```
cordova create MyApp
cd MyApp
cordova platform add (iOS, android, browser, etc...)
```

https://cordova.apache.org/

Answer (score 2):

Following is cordova-based project.

[image]

after creating cordova project, move to cordova-based project in command lind and use other cordova command.

```
cordova create Sample com.sample SampleDemo
cd sample
```

Here Sample is Cordova-based project.

for more info [check here..https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted](https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted)